# Optimum value of the minimum projection

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, vectors

Consider a set of three non-orthogonal vectors $\vec{A}_{1}$, $\vec{A}_{2}$ and $\vec{A}_{3}$ such that norm of each of them is not equal to one i.e. $$||\vec{A}_{i}||\neq 1$$.

Consider a fourth vector $\vec{B}$ whose projection onto $\vec{A}_{i}$ is defined as
$$P_{i}(B)=\vec{A}_{i}.\vec{B}$$
for $i=1,2,3$

Define
$$P_{min}(\vec{B})=\min[P_{1}(B),P_{2}(B),P_{3}(B)]$$
The question is find $\vec{B}$ such that $P_{min}(\vec{B})$ takes the maximum value. i.e. find $\vec{B}^{*}$ such that
$$P_{min}(\vec{B}^{*})=\max_{\vec{B}}P_{min}(\vec{B})$$

Intuitively, I think that for $\vec{B}^{*}$ , $P_{1}(\vec{B}^{*})=P_{2}(\vec{B}^{*})=P_{3}(\vec{B}^{*})$ but I cannot find any reason for it (apart from the fact that it is true when $\vec{A}_{i}$ are orthogonal).

**Edit**

I will give an argument for the support of my intuition below

First note that $\vec{B}^{*}$ will lie within the cone created by $\vec{A}_{1}$, $\vec{A}_{2}$ and $\vec{A}_{3}$. Because if the vector $\vec{B}$ do not lie within the solid angle made by $\vec{A}_{1}$, $\vec{A}_{2}$ and $\vec{A}_{3}$ then

$$P_{min}(\vec{B}) \leq 0$$

As $P_{min}(\vec{B}^{*})=\max_{\vec{B}}P_{min}(\vec{B}) > 0$ this implies that the vector $\vec{B}^{*}$ will only come from the cone made by $\vec{A}_{1}$, $\vec{A}_{2}$ and $\vec{A}_{3}$

Consider that for $\vec{B}^{*}$ which lies within the solid angle created by $\vec{A}_{1}$, $\vec{A}_{2}$ and $\vec{A}_{3}$ we have the following relation

$$\vec{A}_{1}.\vec{B}^{*} > \vec{A}_{2}.\vec{B}^{*} \geq \vec{A}_{3}.\vec{B}^{*}$$

By definition

$$P_{min}(\vec{B}^{*}) \geq P_{min}(\vec{B})$$

Now consider rotation of $\vec{B}^{*}$ with respect to the vector $\vec{A}_{2}$ in such a way that
$$\vec{A}_{2}.\vec{B'}^{*}=\vec{A}_{2}.\vec{B}^{*}>\vec{A}_{1}.\vec{B'}^{*} \geq \vec{A}_{1}.\vec{B}^{*}$$

and

$$\vec{A}_{2}.\vec{B'}^{*} \leq \vec{A}_{3}.\vec{B'}^{*}$$

where $\vec{B'}^{*}$ is the vector obtained by the rotating $\vec{B}^{*}$ with respect to $\vec{A}_{2}$ axis.

Physically we can consider the rotated vector $\vec{B'}^{*}$ to be leaned slightly towards the $\vec{A}_{1}$ axis than $\vec{B}^{*}$.

Thus for the new vector we have
$$P_{min}(\vec{B'}^{*}) \geq P_{min}(\vec{B}^{*})$$

violating the definition of $\vec{B}^{*}$. Thus, the condition
$$\vec{A}_{1}.\vec{B}^{*} > \vec{A}_{2}.\vec{B}^{*} \geq \vec{A}_{3}.\vec{B}^{*}$$

cannot be valid. Which forces us to study whether $\vec{B}^{*}$ satisfies the condition

$$\vec{A}_{1}.\vec{B}^{*}=\vec{A}_{2}.\vec{B}^{*} >
\vec{A}_{3}.\vec{B}^{*}$$

Proceeding in a similar fashion one can show that $\vec{B}^{*}$ cannot satisfy the above condition. Which implies that the only condition $\vec{B}^{*}$ will satisfy is

$$\vec{A}_{1}.\vec{B}^{*}=\vec{A}_{2}.\vec{B}^{*} =
\vec{A}_{3}.\vec{B}^{*}$$

Comments and suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Now posted also on MO: [Optimum value of the minimum projection](https://mathoverflow.net/q/337001).